# How to append a string to the end of a csv file row?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a csv file in app document folder, I get a perticular row by entering the number of the row, now I want to append a small string to that row.

Comment: How are you loading/manipulating your csv?

Comment: Through NSFileHandle... the file is already loaded... so I just read the row... If I use [Filehandling seekEndOfFile] it goes to the end of the file.

Comment: Very simple:  Read the file in, append to the row you want, write the file back.

Comment: can you give me example code please?